# proving $x$ is the generator of a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

Show that $x$ is a generator of $(\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle x^3+2x+1\rangle)^*$. I don't understand part of the solution.

$x^3+2x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3$. Let $a$ be a zero of $x^3+2x+1$ in some extension field of $\mathbb{Z}_3\implies \mathbb{Z}_3(a)\simeq \mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle x^3+2x+1\rangle$.

$\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle x^3+2x+1\rangle \simeq GF(3^3) \implies (\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle x^3+2x+1\rangle)^* \simeq GF(27)^*\simeq \mathbb{Z}_{26}$. Let $x\in (\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle x^3+2x+1\rangle)^*$, then $|x|$ divides $26\implies |x|\in \{1,2,13,26\}$. But the solution says $|x|\neq 1,2$ because $(x-1),(x^2 - 1)\notin \langle x^3+2x+1\rangle$. I understand why $(x-1),(x^2 - 1)\notin \langle x^3+2x+1\rangle$ **but don't understand why we are looking for zeroes in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle x^3+2x+1\rangle$ to find the generator?** Thanks and appreciate a hint.

Comment: What is $f(x)$?

Comment: Corrected that.

Comment: $x$ is most definitely not a zero in $\Bbb Z_3[x]/(x^3+2x+1)$. On the other hand, $x^3+2x+1$ _is_ zero in that ring.

Comment: Corrected that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all $x \notin \langle x^3+2x+1 \rangle$ which means that in fact $x \in R = (\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle x^3+2x+1\rangle)^*$. Let $n = \lvert x \rvert$. Then $x^n = 1$ in $R$ which is equivalent to $x^n = 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle x^3+2x+1\rangle$. The latter means $x^n - 1 = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle x^3+2x+1\rangle$ which is equivalent to $x^n -1 \in \langle x^3+2x+1 \rangle$. Since $(x-1),(x^2 - 1)\notin \langle x^3+2x+1\rangle$, you can exclude $n = 1, 2$. By polynomial long division you also see that $n = 13$ can be excluded.

Note that it is essential to consider the equation $x^n - 1 = 0$ in the **full** ring $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle x^3+2x+1\rangle$ because $0 \notin R$.

Comment: Thanks, May I know why $x^n = 1$ in $R$ is equivalent to  $x^n = 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle x^2+2x+1\rangle$?

Comment: Simply because $R$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle x^3+2x+1\rangle$.

Comment: Appreciate that!